# Writing a get method for LinkedList in Diminished Java (DJ)

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a **Diminished Java (DJ)** program that's supposed to do the following:

> The desired functionality is for your programs to input natural numbers as they’re entered by the user,
> until the user enters a zero. Think of these numbers as getting stored into an array A, with the first
> number entered stored in A[0], the second number stored in A[1], etc. After the user enters the first 0,
> your programs will input two more natural numbers, i and j, and then output the quotient and
> remainder when A[i] is divided by A[j]. If the user enters an i or j value beyond the bounds of A (for
> example, if A’s last element is stored at A[5] but the user enters 6 for the value of i), your program needs
> to print 0 for both the quotient and remainder. You may assume that the user never stores more than
> 10,000 numbers into A.

Example of Desired Behavior:

```
Enter a natural number: 7
Enter a natural number: 2
Enter a natural number: 0
Enter a natural number: 0
Enter a natural number: 1
3 1
(Here A[0]=7 and A[1]=2, so A[0]/A[1] has quotient 3 and remainder 1)
```

My issue is coding a get method to get the element at the index. The LinkedList  **prepends** so it's in reverse order, and I'm not sure how to write a method for it. I need to use a while loop.

Code:

```java
class LinkedList extends Object {
  nat data;
  LinkedList next;

  nat setData(nat newData) {
    data = newData;
  }

  nat prepend(nat newData) {
    LinkedList currList;
    currList = new LinkedList();
    currList.data = data;
    currList.next = next;
    data = newData;
    next = currList;
    0;
  }
  // Problem method
  nat get(nat index) {
    LinkedList temp;
    temp = new LinkedList();

    while(temp != null && index >= 0) {
      temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.data;
  }
}

// Method to divide because we can't do that
nat divide(nat a, nat b)
{
  if( b == 0 ) { 0; }

  else if(a-b == 0) { 1; }

  else if( a < b) { 0; }

  else { ( 1 + divide(a-b, b) ); };
}

// Method to find remainder because we can't do that either
nat remainder(nat a, nat b) {
  if(a < b) { b; }
  else { remainder(a - b, b) };
}

main {
  nat input;
  nat total;
  nat i;
  nat j;

  LinkedList ll;
  ll = new LinkedList();

  input = readNat();
  ll.setData(input);
  total = total + 1;
  while( !(input==0) ) {
    input = readNat();
    ll.prepend(input);
    total = total + 1;
  };

  // While loop ends when user has entered 0. We will now prompt for i and j.
  i = readNat();
  i = total - i;
  j = readNat();
  j = total - j;

  nat remainder = remainder(ll.get(i), ll.get(j));
  nat quotient = divide(ll.get(i), ll.get(j));

  printNat(quotient);
  printNat(remainder);
}
```

If you see any problems with the code, feel free to point it out in a comment. I would appreciate it (although it's not what I'm asking for). Diminished Java is like Java, just replace `int` with `nat`, it also doesn't have nearly as much functionality so if I'm doing something unconventional, that's probably why.

Just hoping this question will still be answerable even if you don't know DJ exactly. I will even accept an answer in Java, and I'll just translate it to DJ. They're that similar. Here's a web document that explains DJ a little more: [https://www.cse.usf.edu/~ligatti/compilers-15/as1/dj/DJ-definition.pdf](https://www.cse.usf.edu/%7Eligatti/compilers-15/as1/dj/DJ-definition.pdf)

Comment: My reading of the requirements you have shown us is that they don't require you to use a list class, let alone implement a linked list class from scratch.  *"You may assume that the user never stores more than 10,000 numbers into A."* - That means you *could* (IMO *should*) just use a fixed sized array of 10,000 elements.

Comment: @StephenC there is no array in DJ. We have to use the LinkedList class from scratch, it was even provided for us

Comment: Fair enough.  So what is your problem with implementing the `get` method?  With a linked list, you just need to follow the linked list "next" pointer "index" times.

Comment: Well, since it gets prepended it's all backwards. So I did total - index to reverse it. I recently updated the code to what I have so far. I'm not sure if it's right/implemented correctly @StephenC

Comment: If you (really) want to store the linked list in reverse, you need to keep track of the current list length (in a variable!) and then follow the links `length - index` times.  It would be better to implement `append` and  use that.

Comment: (Your implementation of `get` has a bug.  You should initialize `temp` to `this` not `new LinkedList()`.)